# Post DataTables row data and receive in MVC controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, datatables

I have successfully been able to integrate DataTables into my MVC project by manually populating the data for the table.

My problem is that I am unable to find a way to elegantly send all row data to my MVC controller and read it correctly.
[image: Sample Table]

When a user hits the Submit Table button I don't know how to correctly scroll through each row and read the data. The JSON.stringify method used in the submit function is problematic to work with because it contains more than just the row data (additional fields) and I can't seem to filter correctly. Maybe a better method exists to post the data? Or I need some special method in my controller?

[image: datatables row Object]

Some sample code I have used to generate the table is below to those who may benefit or find it useful in testing).
Any help you can provide would be great!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css"/>  

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div>
        <div style="width: 100%; float: left; padding: 10px">
            <strong><u>Sample Table</u></strong>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dt_mytable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Column1 Heading</th>
                        <th>Column2 Heading</th>
                        <th>Column3 Heading</th>
                        <th>Column4 Heading</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row 0 Column 1</td>
                        <td>Row 0 Column 2</td>
                        <td>Row 0 Column 3</td>
                        <td>Row 0 Column 4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
                        <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
                        <td>Row 1 Column 3</td>
                        <td>Row 1 Column 4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
                        <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
                        <td>Row 2 Column 3</td>
                        <td>Row 2 Column 4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row 3 Column 1</td>
                        <td>Row 3 Column 2</td>
                        <td>Row 3 Column 3</td>
                        <td>Row 3 Column 4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row 4 Column 1</td>
                        <td>Row 4 Column 2</td>
                        <td>Row 4 Column 3</td>
                        <td>Row 4 Column 4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row 5 Column 1</td>
                        <td>Row 5 Column 2</td>
                        <td>Row 5 Column 3</td>
                        <td>Row 5 Column 4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row 6 Column 1</td>
                        <td>Row 6 Column 2</td>
                        <td>Row 6 Column 3</td>
                        <td>Row 6 Column 4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row 7 Column 1</td>
                        <td>Row 7 Column 2</td>
                        <td>Row 7 Column 3</td>
                        <td>Row 7 Column 4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row 8 Column 1</td>
                        <td>Row 8 Column 2</td>
                        <td>Row 8 Column 3</td>
                        <td>Row 8 Column 4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row 9 Column 1</td>
                        <td>Row 9 Column 2</td>
                        <td>Row 9 Column 3</td>
                        <td>Row 9 Column 4</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="ibox-content">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="submit_table_data()">Submit Table</button>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var oTable_original_data;
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {

        $('#dt_unbinded_machines').DataTable({
            "select": true,
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "order": [[1, "asc"]],  //Order by the Machine binding Status
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": [0], //Hide the first column of idmachine
                    "visible": false,
                    'searchable': false,
                    'serverSide': false,
                }
                //{
                    //'targets': 1, //Disable searching on the idmachine column
                    //'searchable': false
                //},
            ],
        });


        $('#dt_binded_machines').DataTable({
            "select": true,
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "order": [[1, "asc"]]   //Order by the Machine binding Status
        });

        oTable_original_data = $('#dt_mytable').DataTable().rows().data();
    });//Close Document Ready Function

    function submit_table_data()
    {
        //alert("Function submit_table_data called");
        var oTable = $('#dt_mytable').DataTable();

        $('#dt_mytable').submit();
        var row_data = oTable.rows().data();

        // Submit form data via ajax
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/TheController/Function',
            data:
            {
                "row_data": JSON.stringify(row_data)
            },
            success: function (result) {
                //do something
                //alert("Sucesss" + data);
            }
        });
    };
</script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.jqueryui.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: look into the datamapper pattern. this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It is working with DataTables 1.10.0. It will return array of rows.

```
function submit_table_data()
{
   var table = $('#dt_mytable').DataTable();

       $('#dt_mytable tbody tr').each(function () {
           console.log(table.row(this).data());
       });
}
```

Hope it helps.